# Logic for Consecutive Days Push Notifications

Tags: ios, mobile, push-notification

I'm working on a mobile game with increasing daily bonuses based on the number of consecutive days they played (up to 7 days in a row before resetting). I'm looking to increase retention by using push notifications to remind players to log in for their Daily Bonus.

The support staff at our push notification service said this: "This is possible however we don't have any automatic tracking in place for this. It can be done with tags but you will need to add the logic in your app. You could do this by saving the last time the user used your app and then when they come back to your app compare the time. Each time they come back you can just increment your local consecutive days value and then set a tag to match."

If anyone could give advice on how to set this up that would be great. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Are you asking how to track the number of consecutive days that a player has used your game *or* are you asking how to send a push notification every day?

Comment: Why use push?  A local notification could do this quite easily

Comment: Ian, asking how to track the number of consecutive days that a player has used the game.

Paul, already synced up to a push service that provides easy analytics.